# Android address book, with contacts data unreadable from other apps

Tags: android, privacy, contact-manager

The stock Android address book (*com.google.android.contacts*) is great, but I hate that many app can access its data. Just now I was casually trying an app, and realized that the app had sent my whole address book to their server in order to find who among my friends is using that app too.

While permissions can be blocked, it is not really convenient and might be cracked in the future, so  I would like to have the **same app, but just without the API** (intents/content providers) that are used to read from it. That's the surest way to prevent my friends information from leaking.

It means that to call someone I will have to open the app and search for them. It also means that I won't see the name of the caller displayed. I don't mind.

Is there such an address book? I would like to avoid customizing/compiling it for myself.
Requirements:

- Contacts data not readable from other apps
- Import from VCard files (like the stock Android app)
- Free, ideally open source
- Android 5.1.1+
- Does not send any contact data to the Internet. Ideally no Internet permission

Comment: Since you're on 5.1.1, you can simply install [App Ops](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.findsdk.apppermission&hl=en) and deny access to Contacts to all your apps to achieve the same effect. If you upgrade to Marshmallow, this feature becomes native.

Comment: @Huey: Whenever I try a new app (and I try lots of apps), I would have to start App Ops, find that app, modify its settings. That would take a lot of time. If there is a way to disable contact permissions for *all* apps (including apps I will install in the future), that would be great!

Comment: That's what the [new permission system in Marshmallow](http://www.howtogeek.com/230683/how-to-manage-app-permissions-on-android-6.0/) is trying to solve. Under the system, apps prompt you to allow them access to things like contacts, camera, etc. when they need it. But I see where you're coming from.

Comment: But you want to be able to send emails, texts and make calls using this new app, right?

Comment: @Mawg: Yes, I need to be able to run the app, find a person, and press their email address to send an email, or press their phone number to call.